# Custom 404 are not working on Sub folders.. it's work only root level help please

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, cpanel

Custom 404 are not working on Sub folders.. it's work only root level help please

Example: http://www.mysite.com/badpage.htm will return the custom 404 page without a problem.

http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/badpage.htm will not return the custom 404 page. Instead of the custom 404 page with the missing images.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: on both links above I get the same 404 page, so what is actually the problem?

Comment: that's example not original link

Answer (score 0):

Have you place badpage.htm with same content in subfolder, I think you should check check it once if the coding is same and permissions are fine then it should show the same result.